# Plotting list of points to a special graph

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, calculus-and-analysis, matrix

Given Mathematica code of eigenvalues in different variable-paths , I want to add experimental data in the path Gamma-X ; X-Gamma ; and M-Gamma .

Here is the code :

```
f[kx_, ky_] = {{368 + 68*(2.2 - Cos[kx/2]*Cos[ky/2]), -368., 0., 
    0.}, {-368.,368 + 736*(Cos[kx/2] + Cos[ky/2]) + 
    68*(2.2 - Cos[kx/2]*Cos[ky/2]), -368., 0.}, {0., -368., 
    368 + 736*(Cos[kx/2] + Cos[ky/2]) + 
    68*(2.2 - Cos[kx/2]*Cos[ky/2]), -368.}, {0., 0., -368., 
    368 + 68*(2.2 - Cos[kx/2]*Cos[ky/2])}};
    evalues[kx_, ky_] := 0.01 Eigenvalues[f[kx, ky]];
    xkData = {{0, {Pi, Pi}}, {1, {0, 0}}, {2, {Pi, Pi}}, {3, {2 Pi, 
    0}}, {4, {Pi, 0}}, {5, {0, 0}}};
    if = Interpolation[xkData, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
    P1 = Plot[{evalues @@ if[x]}, {x, 0, 5}, Frame -> True, 
    FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, 
    None}, {{{0, "\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(X\), \(_\)]\)"}, {1, 
    "\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(\[CapitalGamma]\), \(_\)]\)"}, {2, 
    "\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(X\), \(_\)]\)"}, {3, 
    "\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(M\), \(_\)]\)"}, {5, 
    "\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(\[CapitalGamma]\), \(_\)]\)"}}, None}}, 
     FrameStyle -> Directive[20, Black], PlotStyle -> {Black, Red}, 
     ImageSize -> 800, GridLines -> {{0, 1, 2, 3, 5}, None}]
```

This is the plot resulted from the code:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
This is just an example of what I wanted. I want to add those black points (dots) in different paths(see the next figure), the problem is that when I try to add such a list of inputs {{x,y}} I get parallel black lines because the inputs are constants to the main interpolation code, i.e when I change the normal x-axis to multiple different paths I think it is causing the issue.

This is the plot I wanna see :
(NB: I added the black points using drawing tool not program)
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

SO HOW CAN I ADD A LIST OF POINTS SUCH LIKE THE BLACK POINTS TO THIS GRAPH?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGCnr.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYHRe.png

Comment: Have you looked at [Epilog](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Epilog.html)?

Comment: It is not clear what points you want. Perhaps, `pts = Flatten[Thread[{#[[1]], evalues @@ #[[2]]}] & /@ xkData, 1];` then as @MelaGo recommended, `Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize[4], Point[pts]}`

Comment: My question is : If I have a given experimental data how can i add it to fit with the plotted curve ? because this graph has many variables paths , that is the problem when I add the data , it seems that it goes constant lines not points or cercles.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion but I still got the lines !